# Facebook login using socialite in laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite

Followed the procedure for facebook Oauth using social lite in laravel

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-login-with-facebook-with-socialiteexample.html

but after i set it up, i am having problem like ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

This is the link that it redirects me:

[https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ffesbok%2Fpublic%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=0R4djYkaHGFEHcXF8CDZQEC52TGvzA82jr77PPp5#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ffesbok%2Fpublic%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=0R4djYkaHGFEHcXF8CDZQEC52TGvzA82jr77PPp5#_=_)

What could be the possible problem? I believe followed everything. Please let me know what i missed.

Comment: In Step 5, whenever something goes wrong processing the callback, this redirects to `auth/facebook` again, trying to trigger the whole auth process again. Remove that redirect, and instead check what the exception actually has to say at this point-

Comment: @04FS thank you for this comment. it helps me debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code I am using for a side project in PROD. so far working without any problem.

I hope it helps you to get this tricky thing done :D, as you can see it is easier than what it looks.

The error might be the way you're setting up your routes to handle the Auth and the Callback, for me it seems that you have the same route for both and that way when Facebook approves and sends the user back, your website redirects again to the OAuth endpoint and so on.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @param $provider
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @param $provider
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);

        auth()->login($authUser, true);

        return redirect('/home');
    }

    /**
     * Finds or creates an user.
     *
     * @param $user
     * @param $provider
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }

        return User::create([
          'name'     => $user->name,
          'email'    => $user->email,
          'provider' => $provider,
          'provider_id' => $user->id,
      ]);
    }
}
```

And this is how we have our services set up (**instead of the env, you can also use the route function**).

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, SparkPost and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    'twitter' => [
       'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID', ''),
       'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
       'redirect' => env('APP_URL', '').'/auth/twitter/callback',
      ],

    'facebook' => [
       'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID', ''),
       'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
       'redirect' => env('APP_URL', '').'/auth/facebook/callback',
      ],

    'google' => [
       'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', ''),
       'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
       'redirect' => env('APP_URL', '').'/auth/google/callback',
      ],
];
```

```
//Routes for socialite
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: Thank you every much! this would help me alot

Comment: If it really helps, would be nice if you can mark it as solution :D, always happy to help.